# unmanaged code can modify method parameters?

Tags: .net, unmanaged

I have a very strange question.
In my wcf server,There are some similar code

```
public MethodAResponse MethodA(MethodARequest req)
{
  LogHelper.Info(JsonHelper.ToJson(req)) // log a
  var r=abc.GetStatus();
  LogHelper.Info(JsonHelper.ToJson(req)) // log b
  ....
}
```

log a is normal,but log b is null.
"req" value was changed
I don't know who changed the local variable.

There are some unmanaged code in abc.GetStatus(),such as

```
[DllImport("F3API.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern long GetCRStatus(IntPtr handle, ref CRStatus status);
```

If I don't use these unmanaged code, the program runs is meeting my expectations
such as

```
public Status GetStatus()
{
  return new Status();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is it `async`??

Comment: @dotctor it's sync